# python tkinter blackjack game, typerror when adding two variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, typeerror

This is my code:

```
from __future__ import division 
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import os
import subprocess
from random import randrange
from random import shuffle
from random import choice
from time import sleep
import sys, time
from select import select


class MyApp(object):

    a = choice(range(1, 12))
    b = choice(range(1, 12))
    money = 100
    bet = 5
    hand = 0


    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("The Game of 21")
        Label(self.root, text="Balance: %d" %(self.money)).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        Label(self.root, text="Choose Bet:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
        Button(self.root, text="5", command=self.bet).grid(row = 2, column = 1)  #create a button
        Button(self.root, text="10", command=self.bet).grid(row = 2, column = 2)  #create a button
        Button(self.root, text="25", command=self.bet).grid(row = 2, column = 3)  #create a button
        Button(self.root, text="50", command=self.bet).grid(row = 2, column = 4)  #create a button

        Button(self.root, text="Deal", command=self.gameOn).grid(row = 5, column = 1)  #create a button
        Button(self.root, text="Exit", command=self.root.destroy).grid(row = 5, column = 2)  #create a button

        self.root.mainloop()

    def gameOn(self):
        """Setup the application's main window as a 2x5 grid"""
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("The Game of 21")
        self.bet = DoubleVar()

        self.cards = StringVar()
        Label(self.root, text = 'Cards dealt:').grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W) #cards dealt
        Label(self.root, text = self.a).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = E)        # card 1 (aka card a)
        Label(self.root, text = ',').grid(row = 1, column = 2)      # inserting a comma between card1 and card2
        Label(self.root, text = self.b).grid(row = 1, column = 3)        # card 2 (aka card b)
        Label(self.root, text = 'Total = %d' %(self.a + self.b + self.hand)).grid(row = 1, column = 4)  # card 1 + card 2
        Label(self.root, text = "Time remaining:").grid(row = 3, column = 1) 

        Button(self.root, text="Hit", command=self.hit).grid(row = 2, column = 0)  #create a button
        Button(self.root, text="Stand" , command=self.stand).grid(row = 2, column = 1) # create a button




#   def bet(betAmount):
#       self.bet = 10

    def hit(self):
        self.hand = choice(range(1, 12))  
        total = self.hand + self.a + self.b 
        dealerHand = choice(range(14,25))


        self.root.destroy()

        result = "Dealer wins. You lose."
        if dealerHand > 21 and total < 22: 
            self.money = self.money - self.bet
            result = "Winner! Winner! Chicken Dinner!"
        if total > 21:
            result
            self.money = self.money - self.bet
        elif total > dealerHand:
            self.money = self.money + self.bet
            result = "Winner! Winner! Chicken Dinner!" 
        elif total == dealerHand: 
            self.money = self.money - self.bet
            result = "Dealer wins. You lose." 
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Results" , "Hand = %d\nDealer = %d\n%s" %((self.hand + self.a + self.b), (dealerHand), result)) # print result


    def stand(self): 
        self.hand = 0
        total = self.hand + self.a + self.b 
        dealerHand = choice(range(14,25))    
        self.root.destroy()

        result = "Dealer wins. You lose."
        if dealerHand > 21 and total < 22: 
            self.money += bet
            result = "Winner! Winner! Chicken Dinner!"
        if total > 21: 
            self.money += bet
            result
        elif total > dealerHand: 
            self.money += bet
            result = "Winner! Winner! Chicken Dinner!" 
        elif total == dealerHand: 
            self.money += bet
            result = "Dealer wins. You lose." 
        print self.money
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Results" , "Your hand: %d\nDealer: %d\n%s" %((self.hand + self.a + self.b), (dealerHand), result)) # print result




MyApp()
```

Basically what I am trying to do is create a blackjack type game, I want to have four buttons (which I've made) and when you click them it changes the `bet` variable. My problem is know even when I try and set a default variable of 5 it won't work; I get a TypeError. I also have no clue how to update the "balance" on the first window as money goes up and down. Sorry for the messy code its been a long day and I think I've done as much as possible on my own.

Edit: The error that pops up is:

```
line 75, in hit
    self.money = self.money - self.bet
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'instance'
```

Comment: can you show the exact error?

Answer (score 1):

`self.bet` is a `DoubleVar`.  In order to get the data that `bet` is holding, you need, `self.bet.get()`

Comment: Seems to be working! Thank you so much. Do you have any idea on how I could get the buttons to change the bet variable?

Comment: @iamtesla -- I do -- there's a bunch of different ways you could do it.  Basically, you need to write a function which accepts an amount and sets the bet accordingly:  `self.bet.set(amount)`.  Then you can create a button:  `bet10 = Button( ..., command = lambda: self.set_bet(10)`.